# Why is component data shared between two independent components with vue-apollo?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I am working on a new project with vue and vue-apollo.

I have one component showing the user name (UserShow.vue):

```
<template>
    <div v-if="!this.$apollo.queries.user.loading">
        Your name is: {{user.firstname}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    export default {
        apollo: {
            user: {
                query: gql`{
                   user (id: 1) {
                     id
                     firstname
                   }
                }`
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and one component for editing (UserEdit.vue):

```
<template>
    <div v-if="!this.$apollo.queries.user.loading">
        Edit your name: <input v-model="user.firstname" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    export default {
        apollo: {
            user: {
                query: gql`{
                   user (id: 1) {
                     id
                     firstname
                   }
                }`
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Both components are shown on the same page, absolutely no mutations involved. just these two simple components.That's all

As soon as I change the name in the input field, the username is updated in the View.

That feels strange to me and I don't like it.

Apollo is doing the query and populating the vue `data()` property of each component. But why is the data shared in some way? `data` in a vue component should be private to this component as long as I don't pass it to a subcomponent (like with v-model in the input field).

If I look into my Apollo Dev Console into the Cache I can't see the change in firstname. So how does it work?

If I don't want this behavior I have only one strange option:

I can add another attribute to the query like so:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="!this.$apollo.queries.user.loading">
        Edit your name:
        <input v-model="user.firstname" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import userQuery from "./user";
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    export default {
        apollo: {
            user: {
                query: gql`{
                   user (id: 1) {
                     id
                     firstname
                     age         // added to create a different query
                   }
                }`
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Adding "age" to the query changes the behavior. That's even stranger! How can I write reliable components with such a behavior? Or did I miss some crucial concept?

Source code can be found here: 
https://github.com/kicktipp/hello-apollo

Bug or feature?

Comment: Is a mutation being called that isn't shown here?

Comment: No. Absolutely no mutation yet. I edit the question

Comment: Maybe it's not Apollo making the change? As far as I'm aware, the apollo cache will only update after a mutation. If none are called, then it seems like something else must be syncing the values.

Comment: I added the code to github and added a link. At the moment the fakeql API does not work as they have a downtime. I hope its working again soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at your code, and I'm pretty sure I know what's going on.

If you read through [this thread](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/issues/68) you'll see that data returned from queries was initially intended by Apollo to be immutable (you shouldn't use it as a `v-model`). In fact, it used to be frozen so attempts to use it as a data source resulted in broken reactivity.

Then [this happened](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/3883). Now the query results are mutable and you are mutating Apollo's internal data.

This explains why one update would immediately modify the display output of another component with an identical query.

Try something like this instead:

```js
import userQuery from './user';

export default {
  data() {
    return { user: {} };
  },
  apollo: {
    user: {
      query: userQuery,
      manual: true,
      result({ data }) {
        this.user = { ...data.user };
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Note the following:

- `user` is initialized in `data`
- `manual: true` is set so `user` isn't automatically set by Vue Apollo
- In `result` we set `this.user` using a spread (or Object.assign) to avoid copying a reference. If the object has more than one level, consider using something like [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

You'll need to make similar modifications in all places where you intend to mutate the query results.

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked into the source code and your are right. Just one note: If you change the data you are not changing the query cache as you wrote, but you change the internal $apolloData object which is referenced inside data. See https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/blob/be6f8c580b0fedc0cff4f509fa4a099968492b95/src/mixin.js#L40